# Маршрутизация в wireguard. Доступ в сеть клиента с сервера и с других клиентов

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, wireguard

Что имеем.

1. Сервер wireguard 10.10.20.1
2. Клиенты, которые подключаются к серверу wireguard
3. Клиент номер один с ip 10.10.20.2
4. Клиент номер два с ip 10.10.20.3

У клиента 10.10.20.2 есть локалка, с диапазоном 192.168.1.x. Что нужно прописать, что бы был доступ с сервера wireguard до сети 192.168.1.x, т.е. до локалки клиента wireguard? А так же, как сделать так, что бы другой клиент 10.10.20.3 имел доступ к сети локалки клиента 10.10.20.2?

P.S Все клиенты ходят в инет через сервер wireguard

Comment: кто клиенты? кинетики?

Answer (score 0):

> Что нужно прописать, что бы был доступ с сервера wireguard до сети 192.168.1.x, т.е. до локалки клиента wireguard?

на сервере для первого клиента необходимо добавить:

```
[Peer]
...
AllowedIPs = 10.10.20.2, 192.168.1.0/24
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ это добавить
```

а также прописать роутинг сети 192.168.1.0/24 на этот адрес:

```
# пример для Linux
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.10.20.2
```

> как сделать так, что бы другой клиент 10.10.20.3 имел доступ к сети локалки клиента 10.10.20.2?

если на "другом клиенте" AllowedIPs выставлено в 0.0.0.0/0, то ничего больше делать и не нужно, если же это не так, добавить сеть нужно и на клиенте:

```
[Peer]
...
AllowedIPs = 10.10.20.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ это добавить
```

Если установлен какой-либо firewall, сконфигурировать на пропуск пакетов необходимо и его.

Comment: `route ...` — просто для справки: [почему ifconfig/route не подходят для диагностики в gnu/linux?](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712)

Comment: спасибо, пропустил ip вначале команды